# Best way to find few documents, (less than 0.01% ) with unusual data in one field using index

Tags: jquery, mongodb, indexing, find, mongo-dart

My app works with MongoDB using `mongo_dart.dart` version 0.7.4+1 .

One of the collections has about 60K documents.

One of the fields in this collection, X, can be empty or contains text.

Almost all the queries search for Docs with X=empty.

I created a Partial Filter Expression, but its not used in Explain Plan

```
partialFilterExpression:{"X":""}
```

Why the partial index not used?

Can I create an index for the Docs with x=empty?

What is the fast way?

Comment: Is an empty field 'x' is the same as x = null, or perhaps x is missing depending on your definition?  In both cases a query `db.collection.find({x: null})` should suffice.  An index on field `x` will help, but you only have 60K records so no big deal either way.

Comment: X is String not null. Could be "ABC" or "".  I have an index but the index not used

Comment: What is the shape of the index, and what is the shape of the query in Mongo (outside of dart)?

Comment: please include sample documents to view also...